# What is proper way to set and compare variable inside an sql trigger

Tags: mysql

Am populating a table using a trigger after an insert event occurs on another table and that worked fine. However i then noticed that the trigger would still insert a new row for existing records. To fix this, I want to create the trigger again but this time it would only fire if a condition is met...but not having previously used triggers in the past am getting a syntax error and not able to identify what am doing wrong. Kindly have a look and help me fix this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `students_gen_insert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `students` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO records (student_id, subject_id)
SELECT new.student_id, subjects.subject_id 
       FROM subjects 
       WHERE category = new.class;
END;
```

Am currently using MySql 5.6.17 version.

Comment: Not sure, but i guess `DECLARE` should be before any "command".

Comment: IIRC, the only `DECLARE` statements that must preceded "code" are those used to set up `CURSOR`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to SELECT from the table the trigger is on, and forbidden to UPDATE or INSERT (not that you are doing those). Assuming you are trying to get the values for the row just inserted, the first SET ... SELECT you have is needless; just use NEW.fieldname to get the fields of the inserted row.

The second SET ... SELECT and following condition are a bit confusing. If referential integrity is being maintained, I would think it would be impossible for the records table to refer to that particular student_id of the students table at the point the trigger is executed. Perhaps this was to avoid the duplicate inserts from the trigger's previous code? If so, it might help for you to post that so we can pinpoint the actual source of redundant inserts.

Comment: Thanks! Using new.subject_id and putting my condition in parenthesis did the trick. Trigger compiled well, however my comparison hasn't managed to stop duplicates unfortunately. Still want to see the previous code i wrote for the first trigger?

Comment: Go ahead and post the original, if the following guess is not right. Is it perhaps because in your insert...select you are not actually filtering on student_id? You can probably just do `SELECT NEW.student_id, subjects.subject_id FROM subjects WHERE category = NEW.class`.

Comment: Wow! Am all smiles right now. You are good, thumbs up. My code works perfectly well now.

Comment: I have edited the code to show the working code now. Thanks a million @Uueerdo